# Hibernate query gives same record multiple times

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on hibernate in eclipse. I am executing simple 'From' query. Here is the code

```
  List list = sess1.createQuery("From Myview").list();
    System.out.println("Records Found :"+list.size());

    Iterator<Myview> i = list.iterator();

    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        Myview nS = i.next();
        System.out.println(nS.getFirstName()+" -- "+nS.getLastName()+" -- "+nS.getAddressLine1());
    }
```

The problem is the list.size() returns 11, which is right as i have 11 records in my table.
But when i am in while loop, the same records shown multiple times and the loop termintes after 11th iteration. here is my output

[image]

here is what i want

[image]

Now you can see that in my output, record is displayed 11 times but the same record is repeated again and again. And what i need is the output displayed in the later image.

Kindly help me in this regard, as i am new to hibernate

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This happens when the id element in your hbm file is not a PK in your DB table. Hibernate treats all rows with the same ID as the same object.

Either change your id element to point to a PK column or use the composite-id element in case your table only has a composite primary key.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the distinct keyword to filter the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the table is correctly filled?
try :

```
List list = sess1.createQuery("SELECT * FROM Myview").list();
```

futhermore, you are getting this list from a view? are you sure that you made this view correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your entity Myview have to implement java.io.Serializable interface

Answer (score 0):

Put the objects returned by Hibernate to a LinkedHashSet and return the LinkedHashSet.

Answer (score -1):

If you have association in the mapping then check if  `fetch=FetchType.EAGER`. If yes then use other fetch type or fetchMode.